# How can I persist html form values using Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm using Flask and doing a contact form. How can I persist form data when returning back to the same view after a user submits the form? I think I've been able to do this in the past using WTForms, but is there another way to do it? WTForms seems overkill for just a contact form. I've tried doing form = request.form right after line 29 and then passing form = form as a variable in render_template(). Obviously, didn't work. If this is only possible using WTForms what is the simplest way to do it? I think writing macros for html element displays is just too much and adds clutter.

```
 @app.route('/contact',methods=['GET','POST'])
 def contact():
     error = None
     if request.method == 'POST':
         if request.form['captcha'] == session["captcha"]:
             # Message(subject,sender,recipients_list)
             msg = Message(request.form['subject'],
                             sender=request.form['email'],
                             recipients=["email@gmail.com"])
             msg.body = request.form['message']
             flash('Message sent')
             mail.send(msg)
         else:
             flash('Invalid captcha')
     session["captcha"] = 'test'
     return render_template('contact.html',page_header='Contact')
```

contact.html:

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}
  {% block body %}

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
          {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
              {% if messages %}
                  <ul class=flashes>
                  {% for message in messages %}
                      <li>{{ message }}</li>
                  {% endfor %}
                  </ul>
              {% endif %}
          {% endwith %}
          <form action="{{ url_for('contact') }}" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email address">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="message">Message</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="captcha">Captcha</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="captcha" name="captcha">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit<    /button>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you post contact.html as well?

Comment: @dirn error = None is a variable I will use in the future to display an error in the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using a forms framework, you'll need to pass the individual data items - subject, email, message - as separate variables, and manually populate them in your template - eg:

```
<input name="email" value="{{ email }}">
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work for textarea. The html renders "missing" inside the textarea. I'm rendernig `value="{{ message }}"` as well as putting `{{ message }}` inside the `<textarea>` tags.

Comment: `textarea` has no `value` attribute so that will never work. `<textarea>{{ message }}</textarea>` works, and it sounds like `message` equals "missing".

Comment: Yeah, I think jinja is reading message as missing. I think the request.form['message'] is not coming through in the POST request.

Comment: So I removed the value attribute from textarea and I'm passing a variable message to render_template the message value is a string, however, still showing as "missing" in the html form.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I couldn't name my textarea "message". I guess because it is the name of item in the message for loop in my html template. I changed it to the_message and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `request` global var:

```html
<input name="email" value="{{request.form['email']}}"">
```